# java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.ResourceSpec; incompatible types for field cpuCores

Tags: apache-beam, flink-streaming

I am using Beam version 1.24 with Flink Session cluster version 1.11 with beam-runners-flink-1.9. When I run the job with remote FlinkRunner in streaming mode, I get the following error. Any insights will be appreciated. I couldn't put all the stack trace as StackOverflows wouldn't let me post with the entire stack trace.

Thanks,
Rao.

Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.flink.api.common.operators.ResourceSpec; incompatible types for field cpuCores

Answer (score 1):

This was due to Flink and Beam version incompatibility; using the Maven artifact that matched the service version solved the issue. Here is the Maven snippet:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-flink-1.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```